# Suggested Sections and exercise of Galois theory from the Dummit and foote or other notable authors .

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I want to start self studying Galois theory by Dummit and foote and I am looking for guidance

It would be great if someone can point out which sections I can leave out and which I most definitely cannot in the first reading. Reading each and every section would be a waste of time

I apologize if this post is inappropriate for MSe.

**My Background:** I have a decent background in  Groups ,ring and Field Theory

Can somebody Please Outline a reading Course For Me in Galois theory by Dummit and foote ?

or can Somebody Please Outline a Reading Course For Me in Galois theory by different authors?

Comment: If you have background in groups, rings, and fields, then you should read every section in the Galois Theory part of Dummit and Foote. Contrary to it being a "waste of time", every single piece of it is necessary to understand Galois Theory. You could probably skip the section on the compass and straight edge though, but that's also interesting in itself.